# How to retain the values of the Spring MVC form backing object?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

My controller has a method to return a form backing object:

```
@ModelAttribute(“userData”)
public UserData formBackingObject() {
    return new UserData();
}
```

When the form submission fails its validation checks, it is redisplayed but when it is re-rendered, the `userData` object does not contain the user-submitted values - only the values present upon initialiation above.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void userData(HttpServletRequest request, @ModelAttribute(“userData”) UserData userData, BindingResult bindResult, ModelMap model) {

    // do validation checks

    if (bindResult.hasErrors()) {
        // perform redirect back to same page
    }

    return "userData";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do a model.addAttribute("key", value) . This will help bind the values to the model object check http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html for sample.

Comment: Also have a look at @SessionAttributes where the values are retained over the session for that instance of controller.

Answer (score 0):

**@ModelAttribute** at method level is generally given to add reference data kind of data to the model. And these annotations are executed before **@RequestMapping**; hence your attribute "userData" is refreshed with new object before control reaches your public void userData(). method.

The solution is to add userData to the model within the method which returns your userdata form jsp to browser.